# Storing JSON array in SalesForce text field

Tags: json, salesforce, apex-code

I need to store some daily data (for the past month) about each of my accounts in SFDC. The data is relatively small (an integer per day per account) and I was wondering if I could take the array for the month, turn it into JSON and store that in a text field on the account object or will I need to create a custom object to house this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly create a custom Text Area(Long) field on Account, assuming you plan to stay within the 32k limit of that field. Something to consider would be to make your JSON non-pretty by removing all the spaces first:

```
str = str.replace(' ', '');
```

Also this approach assumes that each write will completely overwrite your last JSON save. If you wanted to retain a history for these then perhaps a related (lookup) custom object is in order.

FYI - [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) is in live beta now and it's a great place to get questions like these answered.